# How to convert column name of dataframe from string to tuple in python?

Tags: python, string, tuples

I have a dataframe column names which are in form of string I would like to convert it into tuple, which shows the data inside of those column names. I have used "eval" but since its dangerous to use is there any other way to convert?

```
input: dt = "df['cars'],df['bikes']"
output: dt = (df['cars'],df['bikes'])
```

Comment: What do you want to be printed when you run `print(dt)`?
You cannot get `(df['cars'],df['bikes'])` if this is what you want. It will print the entire column instead

Comment: So, basically I am dealing with flask and html. When a user sends a input(say the columns names) it will be received as a string, I want them to be converted into tuple for doing further operation.

Comment: This is a different question. Amend your question or create a new one (delete this one) providing your relevant flask and html code

Comment: please check the below link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65678191/how-to-get-the-column-name-of-dataframe-out-of-string-text-format-to-tuple-in-py

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use spit(',') method

```
dt = "df['cars'],df['bikes']"
tu = tuple(dt.split(','))
print(tu)
```

output: ("df['cars']", "df['bikes']")